# Subdomain http request vs external domain http request speed

Tags: php, api, http, curl

I have a question regarding http requests. I have a web service with api endpoint at the sub-domain of one website but the api is actually used by two websites.

Basically we have website1.com and website2.com and the api server is located at api.website1.com so when website1 is using the api then the request is sent to it's own subdomain. But when the website2 is using the api it is sending request to api.website1.com which is fully external request.

Would it speed up the requests if I clone api server to the subdomain of website2 or there will be no difference in terms of connection speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All else being equal, it makes no difference.

If the sites were hosted on different computers and your change meant that an API would move to the same computer as the site that was making requests to it, then you would reduce the amount of network use which would speed things up.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was thinking about but needed someone to confirm it :)